# while loop prints only one row in the table other rows are below not printed in the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

The problem here is that all values are not printed in the table. I receive all information from the database and only one row is printed in the table, other values are printed below. For, ex when I search for the name "Alex" I have more values with the same name in db and I got them all but only one value is printed in the table.

```
<div id="search">
    <form method="get" action="search_display.php"  id="searchform">
    <h1> Search </h1>
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Traži" /> 
</div>

//search_display.php   file
<?php
     $query = $_GET['query'];
     $min_length = 3;
     if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){

         $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                    FROM clanovi 
                                    WHERE (`IME` LIKE '$query') 
                                    OR (`PREZIME` LIKE '$query ') 
                                    OR (`FIRMA` LIKE '$query')")  or die(mysql_error());

         if(mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0){
            echo "<table border='5'>
            <tr>
              <th>IME</th>
              <th>PREZIME</th>
              <th>FIRMA</th>
              <th>ADRESA</th>
              <th>TELEFON</th>
              <th>FAX</th>
              <th>MOBITEL</th>
              <th>EMAIL </th>
              <th>WEB_STRANICA </th>
              <th>GRAD </th>
              <th>KATEGORIJA </th>
              <th>PROIZVODI </th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){    
            {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['IME'] . "</td>"; 
               echo "<td>" . $row ['PREZIME'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['FIRMA'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['ADRESA'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['TELEFON'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['FAX'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['MOBITEL'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['EMAIL'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['WEB_STRANICA'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['GRAD'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['KATEGORIJA'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row ['PROIZVODI'] . "</td>";    
               echo "</tr>";
            }
          echo "</table>";
         }                 
       }
       else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
           echo "Vaš unos ne postoji u bazi podataka!";
       }
    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
      echo "Minimalna dužina je  ".$min_length. "slova";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try to validate the user input before passing it to query and also keep a note that mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: I suggest you to use some good IDE.SOmething like Netbeans(must install jdk). And format the code while you are writing it.Pozdravi ot Varna ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have invalid syntax for the loop, you have two opening curly braces:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){
{
^ that one is extra
```

Remove one of the two `{`

**Then**

When you don't use `%` with `LIKE` then it is just like using `=` and will only return an exact match. Update your query to add wildcards `%`

```
SELECT * FROM clanovi 
WHERE (`IME` LIKE '%Alex%')
OR (`PREZIME` LIKE '%Alex%')
OR (`FIRMA` LIKE '%Alex%')")
```

Comment: Thank you so much the problem was in { i had extra one. I could not find it.. Once again thanks